# How to make different cells in a collection view go to different view controllers in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to make the different cells each be able to be clicked and bring them to a new view controller.

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell

        let cellLabels = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
        cellLabels.text = arrayOfCellLabel[indexPath.row]
        return cell

    } // # Of Cells
    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrayOfCellLabel.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == 0  {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("box", sender: self)
        }
        if indexPath.row == 1  {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("box1", sender: self)
        }


    }
```

Comment: @Nirav The cells go to the same view controller... I don't know why it isn't working

Comment: You've mixed collection view and table view datasource/delegate methods in this example. This is probably not what you intended and one of these sets of methods is not being called.

Comment: @Jonah how can i fix this?

Comment: use tis  override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
  didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Collection views delegate instead of Table view's delegate

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

 switch (indexPath.row)   {
     case 0:
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("box", sender: self)
     case 1:  
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("box1", sender: self)
   default:
      break
    }

}
```

Comment: how do i set it up in main storyboard?... Do i create a segue from the cell or do i create a segue form the navigation controller...

Comment: as of right now this method isn't working, there is something not aligned in storyboard

Comment: Is the above method getting called first, when you click on a cell.

Comment: I figured it out, I had a button in the cell, I had to remove it and now it works perfectly! Thanks for the help!

Comment: try to replace if else with switch case, it is faster.

Comment: awesome advice will do!